# Numpy array single value issue

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, while-loop

I was working on a problem where I ran into this issue.

```
import numpy as np
str_format = "%H:%M:%S"

a = 0    
b = 0
i = 0

while(i <= 238 ):  

    try:
        opening_time = data_dict['Open'][a]
        opening_time = datetime.strptime(opening_time, str_format)
        x = opening_time

        closing_time = data_dict['Close'][b]
        closing_time = datetime.strptime(closing_time, str_format)
        y = closing_time

        a = a + 1 
        b = b + 1
        i = i + 1

        s = [y - x]

        opening_duration_list = np.array(s)
        print(opening_duration_list)

    except ValueError:

        print("Variable opening Hours")
        a = a + 1 
        b = b + 1
        i = i + 1
```

In this code I'm trying to have it so that each time the loop repeats `s = [Y - X]` it will create a new value in the numpy array.

However, instead it's just created a single value with tonnes of rows. Does anyone have an idea on what I've messed up here and how I can fix it?

Comment: Could you better describe the purpose of your code? Where does "data_dict" come from? What does it contain?

Comment: If you're just trying to add each `y - x` to an array in each loop iteration then create an empty array before the loop with `s = np.empty(SIZE, dtype=object)` and then use `s[i] = y - x` in your loop where `SIZE` in your case is 239.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need to use a numpy array for this. Regular arrays should be fine then you can cast to a numpy array if needs be. Here's a simple solution:

```
result = []
for i in range(0, len(data_dict['open'])):
    try:
        open_time = data_dict['open'][i] 
        closing_time = data_dict['closed'][i]
        opening_duration = closing_time - opening_time
        result.append(opening_duration)
    except ValueError:
        print("Variable opening hours")
final_result = np.array(result)
```

Some questions you might ask here are: What's your reasoning behind this ValueError loop? Why are these two arrays stored in a dictionary? If the values in the arrays returned by this dictionary differ by even one indices then they won't match each other? Wouldn't a better solution be to have a row for each store or day of whatever this is?